# how can i set url of route from AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-routing

WEB (route) :

```
Route::get('/ajax-cat/edit/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\AjaxCRUDController::class, 'categoryEdit'])->name('ajax.categoryEdit');
```

AJAX Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#categoryBtn").click(function () {
        $("#catTable").show();
        let html = '';
        let i = 0;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax-cat',
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                for (const x of data) {
                    html += `<tr>
                                <th scope="row">${++i}</th>
                                <td>${x.name}</td>
                                <td><a href="{{route('ajax.categoryEdit',${x.id})}}" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</a></td>
                            </tr>`;
                }
                $("#catTableBody").html(html);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Picture from Browser:

[image]

But I want Link like this: **127.0.0.1:8000/ajax-cat/edit/2**

Comment: Can you give us more details please? what are you trying to do?

Comment: `{{ }}` is `.blade.php` syntax an will not work in JS. Additionally. `x.id` is a JS variable, and will not work inside of the `PHP` function `route()`. You can't mix and match languages like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot merge different language syntax like this.

`{{ }}`
is from Blade Directive.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade

```
x.id
```

is a variable defined in your javascript code block.

What you can do is:

```
var url = '{{route("ajax.categoryEdit", ":id")}}';
url = url.replace(':id', x.id);
```

Then you can concat your javascript variable inside your html code.